# Como saber quando o app é desistalado no iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notification

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que envia notificação por *push*, mas para que meu servidor não envie notificações para os dispositivos dos quais meu aplicativo foi desinstalado e não poluir o meu servidor, como eu poderia saber quando o usuário desinstalou meu aplicativo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem como determinar se um aplicativo foi desinstalado do sistema.

Porém existe um [serviço de feedback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) que é destinado para informar sobre falhas no envio das notificações, ou seja, quando ela não consegue ser entregue justamente porque o dispositivo de destino não possui mais o aplicativo.

A informação que você obtém desse serviço é uma lista de *tokens*, então, como bem recomendado na documentação, você pode chamar esse serviço diariamente para obter essa lista e fazer uma limpeza em sua base de dados quando necessário.

Links de exemplos usando PHP para obter os feedback:

1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278834/php-technique-to-query-the-apns-feedback-server

2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774681/php-script-for-apple-push-notification-feedback-service-gets-timeout-every-time

3 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943671/how-get-feedback-from-apns-when-sending-push-notification

Comment: Sim eu dei uma pesquisada ontem e realmente é esse o único modo. Vou editar a resposta incluindo links com maneiras de ter acesso ao serviço de feedback. Obrigado @PauloRodrigues.

Comment: Obs importante, o link: 2 realmente funciona! Basta colocar o `cert_desenvolvimento.pem` ou `cert_distriuicao.pem`. Ajustar a variável `#apnsPort` para 2196 e atribuir `$useDev = TRUE;` para fazer testes de desenvolvimento ou `FALSE` para fazer testes/uso real de distribuição.

Apague a primeira linha `funticion checkFeedbackServer($appBundle,$useDev=TRUE) {`
E as chavez `}` no final para trabalhar diretamente no código.

Comment: Fiz uns testes desse serviço e ele é impreciso, pq no feedback vem a data do ultimo push que o app nao recebeu, e nao a data mais antiga do push que nao recebeu. Entao a imprecisão é muito grande, e não serve para o proposito  que tenho em mente.  Pois preciso saber se o app nao recebe o push em um intervalo de tempo de 60 dias. Para garantir q o usuario nao recebe mais o push. Ou entao criar uma logica para guardar esses dados de feedback e criar um historico de pushs nao recebidos.

Comment: Não é que o serviço é impreciso, só não funciona da forma que você queria. A ideia é justamente essa, você manter também uma base de dados de notificações não recebidas e dependendo da quantidade (ou intervalo de tempo) você já deduz que o aparelho não possui mais o seu aplicativo e faz o que deve ser feito.

Comment: Entendi, vou ver outra forma, vou bolar um meio do app manter uma notificacao com o banco, e se a notificacao nao ocorrer num X intervalo de tempo vou considerar como app inativo e notificar o user por email. Obrigado novamente!